# Facebook share button do not take the meta information

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, metadata, meta

The share button require me put the meta to specific the information to share. However , it doesn't work .

> From the facebook object debugger
>
> Response Code：    503
>
> Errors That Must Be Fixed
>
> Missing Required Property：    The 'og:url' property is required, but not
>   present.

**Head**

```
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.yahoo.com">
        <meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/rock.jpg">
        <meta property="og:image" content="http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/bd294ce7ff4c43b6aad4aa4169fb819b.jpg">

        <title>FlipBook</title>

        <style>
        /* Close icon for popup window */
        #close {
        width:44px;
        }
        </style> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="cssv3/style.css" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="cssv3/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.css" type="text/css">
        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Play:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

        <!--[if IE]>
        <script src="js/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <![endif]-->

        <script>
            if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)
                || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i)
                || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)
                || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)
                || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)
                || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)
                || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)) {
                window.location.replace("flipV5_mobile.html");
            }
        </script>

        <!--[if IE]><script src="js/selectivizr.js"></script><![endif]-->
        <script src="jsv3/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
        <script src="jsv3/turn.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jsv3/onload.js"></script>
        <script src="jsv3/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jsv3/jquery.viewport.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jsv3/jquery.scraggable.js"></script>
        <script src="jsv3/jquery.jqprint-0.3.js"></script>

</head>
```

And the code to initial the share button, everything works except the multiple image can not share, so I have to brother the issues of meta. (Should be the only way to share multiple image?)

**body**

```
<a id = "facebook" onclick="return fbs_click()" target="_blank"  title="Share on Facebook"></a>
```

**javascript**

```
    function fbs_click() {
        u=location.href;
        t=document.title;

        window.open("http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[url]=" + u + "&p[title]=" + t + "&p[summary]=paagraphhhhhh",'sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436');
        return false;
    }
```

Is it necessary to use meta name to share multiple image? If yes , how to fix the problem? Thanks.

Comment: on a different note, sharer.php is depreciated. you should be using feed dialogs instead: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Comment: Thanks, I need to register an API key?

Comment: In this way I have to create a new "example app" which is more complex to share button..

Comment: yea youll need an api key. It unlikely, but since facebook doesnt support sharer.php, but content shared via it might not work. Another option is: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/